# Show div depending on select box selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function here that is working:

```
$(function() {
    $('#LEAVE_ENTITLED').change(function(){
        $('.solop').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

What it does is show a div depending on the selection.

For example, the value of the selection is = abc, then it will find the div. with id of abc,

What I wanted to do now is to show this div.

```
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="COURSE" class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2"><span>*</span>Degree/Course:<br>(Write in full)</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="COURSE" name="COURSE"value = "<?= set_value("COURSE"); ?>">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-error col-sm-offset-7">
        <label class="control-label" for="error"><?php echo form_error("COURSE"); ?></label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If I selected any of the following: `GraduateStudies, Trade School, College,
Vocational` from this select box

```
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" for="LEVEL"><span>*</span>Level:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <select class="form-control" name = "LEVEL">
              <option value = "<?= set_value("LEVEL"); ?>"><?= set_value("LEVEL"); ?></option>
              <option value="Elementary"      > Elementary       </option>
              <option value="Secondary"       > Secondary        </option>
              <option value="College"         > College          </option>
              <option value="Vocational"      > Vocational       </option>
              <option value="Trade School"    > Trade School     </option>
              <option value="GraduateStudies" > GraduateStudies  </option>
            </select>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Can you please update my javascript or make me a new one?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle to fiddle with?

Comment: It would be good if you could show some code that you've tried, along with a specific problem you encountered. By the way, I don't see how your second example differs from the first one.

Comment: Please add rendered `html` from browser...

Comment: @Guillaume the first one shows the division depending on the select value, ex. i selected `abc`, it shows `div id ="abc"`, when i select `def` if shows  `div id ="def"`

Comment: the first one is like this, http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/ shows div, depending on select value. the second is i want to show a div, on selected values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select tag class name and bind change event.

check below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.form-control').on('change',function(){
        $('.solop').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```